# Maintain order in ArrayList after sorting and removing duplicates

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

Hello I'd like to add Strings to an ArrayList and then sort it to remove duplicates. The order should remain the same way I added those Strings though. 
What I want: [randomtext, testtext, anothertext]
What I get: [anothertext, randomtext, testtext]

Is this possible or is there an easier way?

```
    ArrayList<String> abc = new ArrayList();

    abc.add("randomtext");
    abc.add("testtext");
    abc.add("anothertext");
    abc.add("randomtext");
    abc.add("testtext");
    abc.add("anothertext");
    abc.add("randomtext");
    abc.add("testtext");
    abc.add("anothertext");

    Collections.sort(abc);      
    for (int i = 1; i < abc.size() ; i++) 
    {
        if(abc.get(i) == abc.get(i-1))
        {
            abc.remove(i);
            i -= 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.print(abc);
```

Comment: So you're actually asking how to sort the array list not in place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to ensure you don't add duplicates whenever you add something to the list.

```
if(!myList.contains(item)){
  myList.add(item);
}
```

If you are receiving a `List` from outside the scope of your method/class, then the easiest may be adding the contents to a `LinkedHashSet` to eliminate duplicates and then getting them back out.  `LinkedHashSet` maintains order.

```
LinkedHashSet<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
set.addAll(myList); // assuming myList is List<String>
myList.clear();
myList.addAll(set);
```

EDIT:  My answer is based on your statements (bold by me for emphasis)

> Hello I'd like to add Strings to an ArrayList and then **sort it to remove duplicates.** The **order should remain the same way I added those Strings** though.

So you're only sorting to remove duplicates.  My answer avoids the sort and puts the burden on `LinkedHashSet`.

Comment: @mri:  You're welcome. If you feel this is the answer you want, don't forget to accept it by clicking on the check mark.

Answer (score -1):

Try this (convert your `List` into `LinkedHashSet`)

```
 Set<String> a = new LinkedHashSet<String>(abc);
 System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: why -1 to this answer?